# django.contrib.gis.gdal.CoordTransform does not work

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, geodjango, django

I want to convert `EPSG:7844` to`EPSG:4326` by using `django.contrib.gis.gdal`. I define `CoordTransform` in this way:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import CoordTransform, SpatialReference
ct = CoordTransform(SpatialReference(7844), SpatialReference(4326))
print(ct)
```

*Output*:

```
Transform from "GDA2020" to "WGS 84"
```

Then I define point

```py
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
point = Point(335810.4049635191, 6235191.808044555, srid=7844)
print(point)
```

*Output*:

```
SRID=7844;POINT (335810.4049635191 6235191.808044555)
```

**And when I apply the transformation, it seems it does not work**:

```py
point.transform(ct)
print(point)
```

*Output*:

```
SRID=4326;POINT (335810.4049635191 6235191.808044555)
```

**Does `django.contrib.gis.gdal` support such transformations? If yes, what am I missing here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EPSG:7844` (https://epsg.io/7844) is a datum, not a projection. That is why the transformation is not possible here.